# Use of moore-penrose inverse when modeling PCA

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, linear-transformations

In the derivation for principal component analysis we model our observed data points **y** as the result of a linear transformation restricted to being an axis change, **W**, applied to a set of uncorrelated variables **x**, where **x** lives in a lower dimensional space than **y**.

Thus, we can represent our observations as **y = Wx**, and what we are trying to find as **x = W'y**, where **W'** is the pseudo-inverse of **W**.

Is the reason we choose to model the mapping of **y** onto the pca axes with use of a pseudo-inverse due to the fact that we want to be able to use PCA on systems where **y** doesn't completely follow our assumptions? Where not all points in **y** are contained in the column space of **W**?

Comment: Precisely.  There won't be an exact solution to the PCA system of equations unless the system has no noise (i.e. there's no deviation from the lower-dimensional structure).  The pseudoinverse yields the least-squares best fit.

Comment: Additionally, the pseudo-inverse exists when $W$ is singular (i.e., does not have an inverse).  This can be caused by some hidden correlation among some of the variables.  (I mean, we *expect* to only need a subspace, so we should *expect* some zero eigenvalues, which obstructs inverting $W$.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with linear regression, there's not much new going on here.

The quantity $\mathbf{x}^* = \mathbf{W}'\mathbf{y}$ is the  solution to $\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{y}$ which minimizes $\lVert \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{Wx}\rVert_2^2$. Minimizing that quantity means finding the subspace with dimension equal to the number of columns of $\mathbf{W}$ such that the data have the lowest squared $L_2$ distance from it.